# Python: Combine then sort list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists; say one of fruits and another of equal length but of unordered numbers:

eg:

```
Fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'kiwifruit'],
Numbers = [3, 2, 4, 1]
```

How can I firstly assign the number

- 3 to apple,
- 2 to banana,
- 4 to pineapple and
- 1 to kiwifruit

and secondly order them according to their new numbers?

i.e

```
sortedlist = ['kiwifruit', 'banana', 'apple', 'pineapple'].
```

My attempts so far have included the enumerate function and the sorted function, but I can't seem to assign and then sort.

Comment: The question has been answered for you, but you really should show some of you own code and attempts you've made already - this sounds like homework.

Comment: I did use the sorted function, but my attempts were quite far off from a good solution. Also, this isn't a homework question.

Comment: You've got a bird in your list of fruits!

Comment: @gnibbler on the off chance you aren't just joking, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwifruit

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, indeed :) It was originally "kiwi" there. As an expat Kiwi (person) it drives me nuts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sortedlist = [x[1] for x in sorted(zip(Numbers, Fruits))]
```

Answer (score 0):

assignment can be done like this

```
In [25]: d = dict(zip(Numbers, Fruits))

In [26]: d
Out[26]: {1: 'kiwi', 2: 'banana', 3: 'apple', 4: 'pineapple'}
```

and then you can sort based on keys of the dictionary

```
In [27]: [d[i] for i in sorted(d.keys())]
Out[27]: ['kiwi', 'banana', 'apple', 'pineapple']
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy is cool for this

```
import numpy as np
fruits = np.array(['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'kiwi'])
sorted_list = fruits[[2, 1, 3, 0]] #note its 0 based indexing ...
print sorted_list
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'kiwi']
Numbers = [3, 2, 4, 1]

New_Fruits = [ Fruits[idx-1] for idx in Numbers ]
```

This only works since your index list (`Numbers`) is sequential integers.  It would even be a little more clean if `Numbers = [ 2, 1, 3, 0 ]`.

The advantage is that it avoids a call to `zip`, so it might be a little more efficient.  The downside is that it is less general.  You need to have an appropriate index list for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'kiwifruit'],
Numbers = [3, 2, 4, 1]
new = []
for x in range(len(Numbers)):
    new.append([Fruits[x],Numbers[x]])
new.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
final = []
for x in new:
     final.append(x[0])
```

Final is the final list